# Why is Linux msync is returning "Cannot Allocate memory"? Is it possible to fix this error code?

Tags: c++, linux

Good afternoon, We are building a prototype deduper for Centos Linux Release x86_32 and Microsoft Windows. One part of the prototype is a MemoryMappedFile program which uses a 1800 element cache. For Centos Linux 5.5 we call msync to synchronize the file with the memory map. For the last several weeks, msync has been functioning okay. 
     Today, msync and perror("msync") are returning "Cannot allocate memory". Why is Centos Linux Version 5.5 x86_32 msync returning "Cannot Allocate memory"? Is it possible for use to fix the "Cannot Allocate memory" error on Centos Linux 5.5 x86_32. Thank you. An excerpt of the memory mapped file program code is shown below:

```
        typedef std::multimap<char *,Range>::const_iterator I;  
    std::pair<I,I> b = mmultimap.equal_range(TmpPrevMapPtr); 
         for (I i=b.first; i != b.second; ++i){ 
    std::deque<Range>::iterator iter;
    iter = std::lower_bound(ranges_type.begin(),ranges_type.end(),i->second);
              if (iter != ranges_type.end() && !(i->second < *iter)){
        sz1 = ranges_type.size();
                        ranges_type.erase(iter);
        sz2 = ranges_type.size();
    }
    }
    erasecount = mmultimap.erase(TmpPrevMapPtr); 
    #if defined(__windows)
    retval = FlushViewOfFile(TmpPrevMapPtr, mappedlength);
    retval =    UnmapViewOfFile(TmpPrevMapPtr);            
    #elif defined(__unix)
         retval = msync(TmpPrevMapPtr,   mappedlength, MS_SYNC);    
    if (retval == -1){                                        
       perror("msync");                                       
         }                                                       
         retval = munmap(TmpPrevMapPtr,  mappedlength);
    if (retval == -1){                    
       perror("munmap");                        
           throw cException(ERR_MEMORYMAPPING,TempFileName);
         }
    #endif
```

Comment: [My guess is that it can't allocate memory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/24/9983984.aspx). Check for memory leaks in your code using something like Valgrind.

Comment: @Billy ONeal, Thank you for your reply. We will use Valgrind to check for memory leaks in our code? Thank you.

Comment: 1. Run `valgrind PATH_TO_YOUR_PROGRAM`. 2. Wait for your program to terminate. 3. Look at the output. The output will be much more useful if Valgrind can find debugging symbols.

Comment: @Billy ONeal, Thank you for reply. We will run valgrind PATH_TO_PROGRAM right now. Thank you.

Comment: @Billy: *"2. Wait for your program to terminate."* Hmmm...make that "wait (possibly a very long time, 'cause valgrind is slow) for your ..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The msync man page states:

```
 ENOMEM The indicated memory (or part of it) was not mapped.
```

That's the errno value perror() prints for you. So you're somehow trying to msync() memory that you've not mmap()'ed from a file.

Comment: +1 because it makes absolutely zero sense to return `ENOMEM` in that condition. (Bill goes and strangles POSIX spec designers) Why not `EINVAL`?

Comment: @Nos, Thank you for your answer. Is there any way we can check if the pointer we pass to mysync was mmap()'ed from a file. Thank you.

Comment: Well, you can print out its value, printf("%p\n",TmpPrevMapPtr); and look through the /proc/<pid>/maps file if there's a mapping. Or you could compare it in code to the pointer and length you got from when you called mmap() that the TmpPrevMapPtr is suppoosed to refer to. However the error already says there's no mapping, so you have a bug  somewhere in your code..

Comment: @Nos, Thank you for your reply. We will check the /proc/<pid>/maps file to dtermine whether there is a mapping. Thank you.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: `EINVAL` is already taken to signal bad alignment. Though I agree that `ENOMEM` a stupid pick. I'd consider `EFAULT` more conclusive, it's what e.g. `read` uses for that exact case.

Comment: @Nos, We checked the /proc/<pid>/maps file while our prototype was running on Centos Linux 5.5 x86_32. The file was empty. Does that mean there was an error in our memory mapping. We also looked in the /var/tmp directory for our temporary memory mapped file. When we use od -c -skip-bytes=54 on our memory mapped file /var/tmp/pdn-XurJyae we see our actual character data. Does that mean our LINUX memory mapped API mmap is partially sucessfull. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Nos, We just checked the /proc/<pid>/map file for our currently running process. It is not empty. It includes several hundred lines. One interesting line is : 9c42c000-9c44c000 rw-s 05e70000 fd:00 30213085   /var/tmp/pdn-XurJyae. We printed the mmap pointer that msync failed on The pointer was 0x9c42f000 which falls into the address range  9c42c000-9c44c000 which is found in our /var/<pid>/maps. Does that mean that a memory mapping exists? If so, why is msync returning "Cannot allocate mmeory"? Is it because of a memory leak? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank No, it's not because of a memory leak. Though, the pointer seems valid, check mappedlength too, to make sure the memory falls within the range.

Comment: @Nos, Thank you for your answer. msync has two arguments , TmpPrevMapPtr and mappedlength. If I understand your most recent answer, even if the TmpPrevMapPtr pointer passed to msync is valid, msync can still fail with the Cannot Allocate Memory error if we pass the incorrect mappedlength argument to msync. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, msync() will try to sync the memory from the gived address and to address + length , that memory have to be within the boudary of the memory mapped file. There's other constraints as well, check the documentation, e.g. the address have to start on a page boundary.

Comment: @Nos, Thank you for answer. We will print out the errno to check if the address does not start on page boundary. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Nos, We are getting a errno of 29 when msync fails. ENOMEM is 12. EBUSY is 16. How should we interpret the errno of 29 when msync fails. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That sounds more like an error with printing the errno value.(perhaps you're printing it after the call to perror or after the call to some other function. You can't do that.) If the code in your post printed  "Cannot allocate memory" it's ENOMEM, which is 12 in linux.

Comment: @Nos, Thank you for your reply. You are correct. I print errno after the call to perror("msync") I think I may have fixed my problem. It turns out I may have been the deleting the TmpPrevMapPtr before calling msync(TmpPrevMapPtr,minmappedlength). I printed out the addresses of amd mapped lengths after the MapPtr = mmap(NULL,,,,,,,) the  called and compared all the MapPtr addresses and mapped lengths with the msync TmpPrevMapPtr and minmapped length Whenever the MapPtr equals the TmpPrevMapPtr, the two mappedlength's are equal. Becuz I have  25 characters, I will print the answer. Thank you

Comment: @Nos, I just checked some documentation on the Internet about std::deque::erase() std::mmultimap::erase() and it appears that std::deque::erase() and std::mmultimap does not delete a TmpPrevMapPtr Pointer. Could you please tell me if this is true on g++ 4.1.2? Thank you for your help.